# SDL Destructor Called too early

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm programming a tile-based map in SDL, and the constructor of the `Map` class is being used to set the image used to represent each `MapCell` object contained within it. However, I'm having an issue with the destructor of my `Sprite` class that's being used to free the `SDL_Surface*` the object holds. The destructor is being called early, and I'm not entirely sure why. Here's a stripped-down version of my `Map` constructor just showing how the cell's sprites are allocated.

```
Map::Map(string fileName, int tileWidth, int tileHeight)
{   
    string mapData = ReadMap(fileName);
    _cells = new MapCell[_width*_height];

    for(int y = 0; y < _height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < _width; x++)
        {
            int currentCell = y*_width+x;

            if(mapData[currentCell] == '0' || mapData[currentCell] == 'P' || mapData[currentCell] == 'X')
            {
                _cells[currentCell]._sprite = Sprite(Point2D(x*tileWidth, y*tileHeight), "Assets/Graphics/Grass.bmp");
                if(mapData[currentCell] == 'P')
                    _cells[currentCell]._sprite = Sprite(Point2D(x*tileWidth, y*tileHeight), "Assets/Graphics/Player.bmp");
                if (mapData[currentCell] == 'X')
                    _cells[currentCell]._sprite = Sprite(Point2D(x*tileWidth, y*tileHeight), "Assets/Graphics/Target.bmp");
            }
            else if(mapData[currentCell] == '1')
                _cells[currentCell]._sprite = Sprite(Point2D(x*tileWidth, y*tileHeight), "Assets/Graphics/Wall.bmp");
        }
    }
}
```

The destructor seems to be called immediately after the Sprite object is created. What am I missing here? I've also tried allocating the `_sprite` member of `MapCell` on the heap, but it causes the same issue. As far as I can tell, it's not going out of scope because the `Sprite` object created is part of the `Map` object.

The following are my constructors and destructor for the `Sprite` class:

```
Sprite::Sprite(void)
{
    _texture = NULL;
    _position = Point2D::Zero();
}

Sprite::Sprite(Point2D position, std::string texPath)
{
    _texture = Content::LoadBMP(texPath);
    _position = position;
}

Sprite::~Sprite(void)
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(_texture);
}
```

Here's my Main if it helps at all:

```
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    const int TILEWIDTH = 32;
    const int TILEHEIGHT = 32;

    // Initialization
    InitSDL();
    Map map = Map("Assets/Maps/Map3.txt", TILEWIDTH, TILEHEIGHT);
    Window::SetSize(Rectangle(0, 0, map.GetWidth()*TILEWIDTH, map.GetHeight()*TILEHEIGHT));

    PathFinder pathFinder = PathFinder();
    List<Point2D> path = pathFinder.FindPath(map, map.GetPlayerStart(), map.GetTarget());
    List<Sprite> PathNodes = List<Sprite>();
    for(int i = 0; i < path.GetCount(); i++)
        PathNodes.Add(Sprite(*path(i)*32, "Assets/Graphics/PathNode.bmp"));

    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event Event;

    while(quit == false)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event))
        {
            if(Event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                quit = true;
        }

        map.Draw();

        for(int i = 0; i < path.GetCount(); i++)
        {
            if(PathNodes(i)->GetPosition() != map.GetPlayerStart()*32 && PathNodes(i)->GetPosition() != map.GetTarget()*32)
                PathNodes(i)->Blit();
        }

        Window::Flip();
    }

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the assignment `x._sprite = Sprite(...)`. This creates a `Sprite` temporary, copies its fields into `_sprite`, then *destroys the temporary*. Furthermore, it does *not* call the destructor on `_sprite` before doing the assignment, so the old `_texture` will just leak.

If you want to avoid that, have a `.set` or `.load` function on `Sprite` to update the contents of the `Sprite` instead of copying, and create *private* assignment and copy-constructor methods to avoid accidental abuse.

Comment: Exactly : The "Rule of 3" and boost::noncopyable are the important bits here.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < path.GetCount(); i++)
        PathNodes.Add(Sprite(*path(i)*32, "Assets/Graphics/PathNode.bmp"));
                    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    // a temporary here!
```

When that expression finishes, the destructor of temporary `Sprite` gets called, frees the surface and leaves `PathNodes` objects with a dangling pointer to a freed surface. There's probably more such expressions in your code.

Obey [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and write a proper copy constructor and assignment operator for `Sprite` class.

See [the documentation](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Surface) of`SDL_Surface` to see what needs to be done (you'll may have to increment the `refcount` member of the surface manually).

Comment: In this case, to avoid mucking with refcounts, it may be simpler to simply privatize the copy-constructor and assignment methods. This way, you ensure that each texture is only associated with a single `Sprite` object.

Comment: If that's viable for OP, sure. Or possibly make `_texture ` `std::sharer_ptr` with `SDL_Freesurface` as deleter.